# PHP multiple OR logical operators in one IF statement

Tags: php

I have a question about IF statements with multiple logical OR operators.

If we let:

```
$x=1;
```

A. I typical would write a IF statement comparing two items like this:

```
if($x == 1 || $x == 2) echo 'good';
else echo 'bad';
```

B. But, is this a valid IF statement? If not, why?  (because it seems to work)

```
if($x == (1 || 2)) echo 'good';
else echo 'bad';
```

C. I typical would write a third comparison like this:

```
if($x == 1 || $x == 2 || $x == 3) echo 'good';
else echo 'bad';
```

D. What about this, following suit with B, above? (it does not seem to work)

```
if($x == (1 || 2 || 3)) echo 'good';
else echo 'bad';
```

The example in B, above works, but not the example in D.  Why?

I cannot find any PHP documentation as to why.

Comment: B doesn't really work.

Comment: Only A and C are correct.

Comment: Use `var_dump(1 || 2)` to see what you're actually comparing with.

Comment: @Barmar Well, technically it works, but not how he thinks it does. B and D are wrong...

Comment: B, does work. See here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e57976d0fff29ed2de58f4816018a3c28a7b1da

Comment: @digitalniweb If it doesn't do what's intended, it doesn't really "work". Just because something runs, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think what Barmar means is that it happens to work by coincidence or chance, as opposed to _by design_.  With other values, it will definitely _not_ work

Comment: You're running into issues with loose comparisons (`==`) vs strict comparisons (`===`). When you do `$x == (1 || 2)` it's actually being converted to `$x == true` because `1 || 2` is truthy. And `$x = 1;` is truthy, so it's acting like it works. (But `$x = 3;` is also truthy... so try that and see what happens). But if you were to do `$x === (1 || 2)` it would then compare `$x === true` which isn't true, because `$x` is an int. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php for more info.

Comment: Then try `$x = 3;`

Comment: With $x=3; if($x == (1 || 2)) it evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: So, I guess it was working by coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happens for every version:

### A. `$x == 1 || $x == 2`

PHP will compare `$x` with the value `1`, this is `true` so it can short-circuit the `if` and `echo 'good'`.

### B. `$x == (1 || 2)`

PHP will evaluate `1 || 2` because parentheses indicate the priority, as the result should be a boolean expression it will [cast `1` to a boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) which evaluates to `true` so the expression becomes `$x == true`.

Now PHP will evaluate this expression. First it will cast both types to the same, according to [the documentation, it will "Convert both sides to bool"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). So, same as above, as `$x` is `1` it will be cast to `true` and then the expression becomes `true == true` which is `true`.

### C. `$x == 1 || $x == 2 || $x == 3`

It is the same as A.

### D. `$x == (1 || 2 || 3)`

It is quite the same as B.

And, for the record [`1 == (1 || 2 || 3)` evaluates to `true`](https://3v4l.org/sDF6e).